# Ubuntu проблема службы маршутизации

Tags: ubuntu

Не работают ни локальные сайты, ни обычные. 
Ping google показывает, что с инетом все в норме.

Что делать? 
Подозреваю, что проблема в lo т.к. nmcli показывает, что lo и enp1s0 не настроены.

Comment: Чё `ifconfig -a` выдаёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно было поставить настройку "Сетевые прокси" - "Автоматически". После того как выключал ПК предварительно забыв выключить ВПН данная настройка сбивалась и приходилось заново переводить ее в режим "Автоматически".